# Spark in other webserver

Tags: spark-java

I'm confuse when reading documentation of spark to deploy a spark application in other web server like Jboss
Can I have an "hello word" sample to run spark application in other web server?
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found a tomcat sample https://github.com/paulkav1/spark_tomcat_example i'll try to deploy it in jboss7 latter, i hope it'll work in jboss7 without problem